# How can I show the unit circle in z-plane maps to a line?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

For example, it is known that if |c| = |d|, then the linear fractional transformation:

$w(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, ad-bc \neq 0$ should map the unit circle ($z=e^{i \theta})$ to a line.  How would I know that, and see what line that the function maps to.  $w(z),z \in \mathbb{C}$ of course.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you know that $w$ maps circles to lines or circles, the reason it has to be a line is that $w(-d/c)=\infty$ and $-d/c$ is on the unit circle.  You could find which line by plugging in any two points from the circle other than $-d/c$.

Comment: Okay, but for example given |c| = |d| how would I be able to show the circle maps the unit circle to a line?

Comment: Every line pass through $\infty$, for this you may take $cz+d=0$ to goes $\infty$. if $z$ lies on unit circle so let $z=e^{i\theta}$ then $ce^{i\theta}+d=0$ shows $ce^{i\theta}=-d$ or $|c|=|d|$.

Comment: @MyGlasses: It is assumed already that $|c|=|d|$, which implies that $-d/c$ is on the circle, and $w(-d/c)=\infty$.  It seems you are arguing in the other direction. J. Doe: I don't know what you know about these mappings already.  Perhaps you are learning them from a reference that shows lines and circles are mapped to lines or circles.  You didn't respond to my "If you know...".  You say "Okay" but I don't know which part is okay.

Comment: Well I think OP problem is in this manner.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I understand the fact that $w(-d/c) = \infty$, and how if |c|=|d| then $-d/c$ is on the circle, but how does knowing these two facts allow us to know absolutely that the circle then maps to a line?

Answer (score 1):

The following is an elementary proof which assumes no prior knowledge of [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). From the given relation:

$$w(cz+d)=az+b \quad\iff\quad z(wc-a)=b-wd \tag{1}$$

Taking the complex conjugate of both sides:

$$\bar z(\bar w \bar c- \bar a)=\bar b-\bar w \bar d \tag{2}$$

Multiplying $(1)\cdot (2)$ and dropping $z \bar z = |z|^2=1\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
(wc-a)(\bar w \bar c- \bar a)=(b-wd)(\bar b-\bar w \bar d) \\
\iff\quad |w|^2|c|^2 - wc\bar a - \bar w \bar c a+|a|^2=|b|^2-w \bar b d - \bar w b \bar d + |w|^2|d|^2 \\
\iff\quad \cancel{|w|^2\left(|c|^2-|d|^2\right)} +w(\bar b d - \bar a c) +\bar w(b \bar d - a \bar c) + |a|^2-|b^2| = 0
$$

The first term cancels out in the latter equation because $|c|=|d|\,$, then what remains is an equation of the form $\alpha w + \bar \alpha \bar w + \lambda = 0$ with $\alpha=\bar b d - \bar a c$ and $\lambda = |a|^2-|b^2| \in \mathbb{R}$ which [represents a line](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equation_of_Line_in_Complex_Plane) in the complex plane.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Plugging in values of $z$ on the unit circle $|z|=1$ will give corresponding points on the $w$ line. For example $z=\pm 1$ shows that the line passes through $\,\frac{a+b}{c+d}\,$ and $\,\frac{a-b}{c-d}\,$ (when $\,c \ne \pm d\,$).

The intercepts with the axes can be determined by solving for $w = \pm \bar w\,$. For example the real axis intercept must satisfy $w=\bar w$ and calculates to $w=\frac{-\lambda}{\alpha + \bar \alpha}=\frac{-|a|^2+|b|^2}{\bar b d - \bar a c+b \bar d - a \bar c}\,$ (when $\Re(b \bar d-a \bar c)\ne0$).